# Refreshing contents of an XML file dynamically

Tags: c#, xml, database

I have an XML file which contains data from a SQL `DataSource`. I need to refresh the file dynamically when new data is added to the database.

Comment: what is the problem? any reason you can't overwrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [DataSet.GetXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.dataset.getxml.aspx)

After you query your database and fill the adapter, If you detect data changes then
use the filled dataset to save the XML to disk:

```
string file ="c:\\newxml.txt";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file, ds.GetXml());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into database triggers - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx.

Create an insert trigger which will populate or update the xml file when the data is added.  This should be a viable solution is there isn't allot of inserts going on.